# How to match names with slash in C# regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long text which contains strings like these:

```
...
1.1SMITH/JOHN 2.1SMITH/SARA
...
1.1Parker/Sara/Amanda.CH07/Elizabeth.IN03
...
```

Is there any regular expression in C# which can match these names. The clue is to search for [A-Z] which has separated by '/'.

Comment: and your expected outputs are ?

Comment: The line which contain the names satisfies me. There are lots of other strings, I want names only. you know, I want a match like [A-Z]+/[A-Z]+, but this does not work.

Comment: even though you already markes it as solved: do you really also want to match *CH* an *IN*?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[a-zA-Z\/]+
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/9Qa071/1)

c# sample:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z\/]+";
        string input = @"...
1.1SMITH/JOHN 2.1SMITH/SARA
...
1.1Parker/Sara/Amanda.CH07/Elizabeth.IN03";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

[You can test the working c# sample here](http://ideone.com/g8GI91)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[a-z\/]+
```

which matches any combination of characters and slashes [(see Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tR1EoI/2)).

Make sure you are matching case-insensitive.

```
var expression = new Regex(@"[a-z\/]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var names = expression.Matches(theText, expression);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to capture any [A-Za-z] which has a previous char or next char equals '/'?

Try this:

`(?<=\/)[A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+(?=\/)`

Comment: I shouldn't split names. They should be altogether.

Comment: Your answer sparates Amanda from Sara and Parker. But I want a whole.